# What is the definition/usage of make out?

Tags: word-usage

What is the definition and usage of make out?

It is hard to search for definition/usage of phrases(as it is not vocab) over the internet

Comment: If you want to search for a phrase on Google, put it in quotes. So type "make out" and then the first result will be the definition,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. distinguish/identify something, manage to see or read something

The ship captain could not make out the name of the other boat because of the fog.

I was unable to make out the sign because I didn't have my glasses.

2. make someone believe something, prove something

He made out that he was at the library last night but I know that he wasn't.

3. understand something by making an effort

I can never make out what my friend wants to say when he phones me.

4. to progress, to do well or not do well

"How did you make out at your job interview yesterday?"

make out a report 】

make out a report

• make out (a report/application)

fill out a report/application

I stayed out late last night in order to make out some reports for work.

make out an application 】

make out a report

• make out (a report/application)

fill out a report/application

I stayed out late last night in order to make out some reports for work.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that you would find it hard to search that. Googling `define make out` yields very acceptable output:

> make out: phrasal verb of **make**
>
> *informal*
>
> 1. make progress; fare. "how are you making out, now that the summer's over?" synonyms:   get on/along, fare, do, proceed, go, progress,
>    manage, survive, cope, get by. Example: "how did you make out?"
> 2. (NORTH AMERICAN) *informal* engage in sexual activity. "Ernie was making out with Bernice" synonyms:   kiss, neck, caress, pet; informalsmooch,
>    canoodle, fool around. Example: "they made out in the back seat"

Comment: I found that NA definition slightly misleading. Making out doesn’t include “going all the way” which I *would* include in “engage in sexual activity”  Their synonyms are more accurate.